# insert function in BinarySearchTree (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
 public void insert(String word,String def){
    Node newNode = new Node(word, def);
    if(root==null){
        root=newNode;
    }
     Node p, q ;          
    p = q = root ;      
    while (q != null){  
        p = q ;  
        int c = word.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getWord());
        if (c < 0) {
            q = p.getLeft() ; 
        }
        else{
            q = p.getRight() ;
        }
    }
    int c = word.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getWord());
    if (c < 0) {
        p.setLeft(newNode);
    }
    else{
        p.setRight(newNode);
    }
    
}
```

> I wrote this code to insert nodes in a binary search tree but it is not working as planned.

It enters the root and one node after root after it runs infinitely.
I cannot find any solution for this.

Comment: I think you are missing a `return` statement in your `if(root==null)` if you want to insert the new node as root when the tree is empty.

Comment: Not necessarily a solution, but shouldn't you return from `if (root == null)` or put the rest of the method in an `else` block?

Comment: @Slaw yk you have solved the problem

Comment: @Slaw idk why didn't i thought of this in the first place .ThankYou very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void insert(String word,String def){
        Node newNode = new Node(word, def);
        if(root==null){
            root=newNode;
        }else{
         Node p, q ;
        p = q = root ;
        while (q != null){
            p = q ;
//            int c = word.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getWord());
            if ( word.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getWord())<0) {
                q = p.getLeft() ; 
                
            }
            else{
                q = p.getRight() ;
                
            }
        }
//        int c = word.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getWord());
        if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getWord())<0) {
            p.setLeft(newNode);
        }
        else{
            p.setRight(newNode);
        }
        } 
    }
```

> I tried this by just putting my code in if else and now it runs fine. @slaw helped me with this.